# How to remove line breaks that lodash templates create?

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

I am rendering HTML from lodash templates (using webpack) but lodash templates are creating new line breaks. Beautifying the HTML will not help as those lines are not "mistakes".

What I use:

```
<!-- Theme
============================================= -->
<%if (theme == "main") { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />
<% } %>
```

The result. New line breaks above and below the HTML `<link>`

```
<!-- Theme
============================================= -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />
```

This is how I want it without any new line breaks above and below:

```
<!-- Theme
============================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />
```

There is a hack to do it all in one line like this but this will get ugly with long code.

```
<!-- Theme
============================================= -->
<%if (theme == "main") { %><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" /><% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.trim()` to remove `\n` from the start and end of the result, and `_.replace()` with a RegExp to convert multiple consecutive `\n` to a single one:

```js
const str = `<!-- Theme
============================================= -->
<%if (theme == "main") { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />
<% } %>`;

const compiled = _.template(str);

const fn = _.flow([
  compiled,
  str => _.trim(str, '\n'),
  str => _.replace(str, /(\n)\1+/, '$1'),
]);

const result = fn({ 'theme': 'main' });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```